# Nodeunit test.throws doesn't seem to catch the error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, nodeunit

I am trying to create a test suite for a module that I am writing in Node.js using Nodeunit.  The module is a basic music playlist that allows adding and removing tracks to the playlist.

```
var playlist = function(){
    this.__playlist = [];
    this.__count = 0;
};

playlist.prototype = {
    addtrack:function(track){
        if(typeof track !== "object") throw new Error("Track needs to be an oject");
        this.__count++;
        track.id = this.__count;
        this.__playlist.push(track);
        return this.__playlist;
    },
    removetrack:function(trackid){
        if(typeof trackid !== "number") throw new Error("Pass in a numeric track id");
        var trackFound = false;
        for(var i=0;i<this.__playlist.length;i++){
            var t = this.__playlist[i];
            if(t.id == trackid){
                trackFound = true;
                this.__playlist.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
        if(!trackFound) throw new Error("Track not found in the playlist");
        return this.__playlist
    }
}

exports.playlist = function(){
    return new playlist();
}
```

As you can see there are places that throw errors based on incorrect data being passed in.

So here is my test suite.

```
var pl = require('./playlist');

exports.testPlaylistInit = function(test){
    var playlist = pl.playlist();
    test.equal(typeof playlist, 'object');
    test.done();
}

exports.testAddingTracks = function(test){
    var playlist = pl.playlist();
    test.throws(playlist.addtrack(), Error, 'Should fail for blank track');
    var track = {
        title: "Golly Sandra",
        artist: "Eisley",
        album: "Room Noises"
    };
    tracks = playlist.addtrack(track);
    test.equals(tracks[0],track);
    test.equals(tracks[0].id,1)
    test.done();
}

exports.testRemoveingTracks = function(test){
    var playlist = pl.playlist();
    test.throws(playlist.removetrack('Imma error'), Error, 'Show fail for non-numeric track id');
    var track = {
        title: "Golly Sandra",
        artist: "Eisley",
        album: "Room Noises"
    };
    playlist.addtrack(track);
    track = {
        title: ".44 Calliber Love Letter",
        artist: "Alexisonfire",
        album: "Alexisonfire"
    }
    playlist.addtrack(track);
    test.equals(playlist.removetrack(1)[0],track);
    test.throws(playlist.removetrack(10), Error, 'Should fail for non-existant track');
    test.done();
}
```

While writing the test suite I used test.throws as the assumption basically just wraps the code block in a try-catch statement and checks the catch against the error block.  Apparently I am wrong though, because when I run the test with Nodeunit, Node displays the error message thrown by the module instead of the test suite catching the error.  Am I using the test.throw case incorrectly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your usage of test.throws isn't quite right. If you look at what you have:

```
test.throws(
  playlist.removetrack('Imma error'),
  Error,
  'Show fail for non-numeric track id'
);
```

You are executing `playlist.removetrack('Imma error')`, and then passing the result of that to throws, so if there is an exception, it will happen before throws is ever executed.

You should do something more like this:

```
test.throws(
  function() {
    playlist.removetrack('Imma error');
  }, 
  Error,
  'Show fail for non-numeric track id'
);
```

You must pass in a function, that when executed, will try to remove the track. That way, your playlist logic is actually executed by the throws function, and thus can automatically be wrapped in a try/catch block.

Comment: perfect, golden.... perhaps similar example should be added to the readme for nodeunit ;)